# Do I need a threadpool to manage multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

I've got a set of Java classes which implement a relatively high frequency  polling solution which uses FutureTasks running on separate threads so the system remains responsive while the future tasks do their polling of remote servers..  these threads are pretty short lived, they can do their work in in about 200ms and I only need to run on task at a time, but I need to poll at the rate of every 2 seconds or so.

So every two seconds I'm creating a new thread which I keep in a private field, and then when its done its work I just set it = null, and then recreate it.  Is that going to cause problems?

Comment: No, but it is more efficient and more easily configurable to do so.  There is overhead in creating new threads, so if they are shorted lived, why not make use of one, it will reduce strain on the GC and make the process faster...I'm assuming you're using an `ExecutorService` of some kind?

Comment: Can you show some code? From what you say, it sounds like a job for a `ScheduledExecutorService`. And whatever `ExecutorService` you use, there will be an underlying `ThreadPool` indeed. So, what do you want to know exactly?